# Error loading image on server

Tags: php, mysql

Good morning, I do not speak English well, I'm from Brazil and I'm using the Google Translator.

I'm sorry for mistakes in my English.

I'm having trouble with my banner creation site

When I upload the image does not load on the server

when entering the site console I get these errors see the image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugVDa.jpg)

The code of the HTML file does not give to put here poker is very large

Banner Maker Link
[enter link description here](https://www.lojavirtualbanner.com.br/criador-de-banner/criador.html)

Thank you very much for the help.

This is the code upload_photo.php

```html
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/criador-de-banner/config/settings.php');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/criador-de-banner/php/functions.php');

$main_folder=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/photos/';
$year_folder=date("Y").'/';
$month_folder=date("M").'/';
$full_path=$main_folder.$year_folder.$month_folder;

if (!file_exists('../photos/'.$year_folder))
 {
  makeDir($year_folder);
 }
if (!file_exists('../photos/'.$year_folder.$month_folder))
 {
  makeDir($year_folder.$month_folder);
 }

 $s_ext=strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
 $uniqid=uniqid();
 $destination = $uniqid.'.'.$s_ext;

$temp_image=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
if (getMimeType($temp_image))
 {
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["name"], $full_path.$destination);
 echo '/photos/'.$year_folder.$month_folder.$destination;
 }else{
 echo 'error'; 
 }
?>
```

This is the code functions.php

```html
<?php
//-------------------FTP functions-------------------------

    function makeDir($the_dir)
 {
 $dir = ROOT_FOLDER.'photos/'.$the_dir;
 $conn_id = ftp_connect('localhost');
 $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, DB_USER, FTP_PASS);
 if (ftp_mkdir($conn_id, $dir)) {
  ftp_chmod($conn_id, 0777, $dir) !== false;
  }
 ftp_close($conn_id);
 } 

//-------------------Image functions-------------------------

function getMimeType($filename)
{
    $mimetype = false;
    if (function_exists('getimagesize')) {
       $mimetype = getimagesize($filename);
    } elseif(function_exists('exif_imagetype')) {
       $mimetype = exif_imagetype($filename);
    } elseif(function_exists('mime_content_type')) {
       $mimetype = mime_content_type($filename);
    }
    return $mimetype;
}
?>
```

This is the code upload_image.js

```js
var _$_f464=["holder","getElementById","undefined","draggable","span","createElement","FormData","upload","filereader","formdata","progress","uploadprogress","className","fail","hidden","forEach"," ","split","filereader formdata progress","type","onload","","html","div","children","#holder","src","result","target","firstChild","insertBefore","readAsDataURL","Only image files are acceptable.","file","append","POST","php/upload_photo.php","open","value","innerHTML","responseText","error","log","Por favor, Espere...","filter","alpha(opacity=0)","css","opacity","0",".canvas_container","height","attr","width","hide","#image_canvas","max-height","95%","max-width","100%","drawImage","197px","#desaturate","desaturate","2d","getContext","#sepia","sepia","#grayscale","grayscale","#addnoise","addnoise","#expose","expose","#tint","tint","#vignette","vignette",".dragNdropImagePanel","show",".EditImagePanel","1","alpha(opacity=1)","animate",".aligner","find","fadeIn","scale","btn_disabled","addClass",".load_the_image","removeClass",".open_load_image_panel",".editImagePanel","onprogress","lengthComputable","loaded","total","send","dnd","ondragover","hover","ondragend","ondrop","preventDefault","files","dataTransfer","onchange","input","querySelector","click","trigger","#file_form","on","change","prop"];var holder=document[_$_f464[1]](_$_f464[0]),tests={filereader: typeof FileReader!=_$_f464[2],dnd:_$_f464[3] in document[_$_f464[5]](_$_f464[4]),formdata:!!window[_$_f464[6]],progress:_$_f464[7] in  new XMLHttpRequest},support={filereader:document[_$_f464[1]](_$_f464[8]),formdata:document[_$_f464[1]](_$_f464[9]),progress:document[_$_f464[1]](_$_f464[10])},acceptedTypes={"image/png":true,"image/jpeg":true,"image/gif":true},progress=document[_$_f464[1]](_$_f464[11]),fileupload=document[_$_f464[1]](_$_f464[7]);_$_f464[18][_$_f464[17]](_$_f464[16])[_$_f464[15]](function(api){if(tests[api]===false){support[api][_$_f464[12]]=_$_f464[13]}else {support[api][_$_f464[12]]=_$_f464[14]}});function previewfile(file){if(tests[_$_f464[8]]===true&&acceptedTypes[file[_$_f464[19]]]===true){var reader= new FileReader();reader[_$_f464[20]]=function(event){$(_$_f464[25])[_$_f464[24]](_$_f464[23])[_$_f464[22]](_$_f464[21]);var image= new Image();image[_$_f464[26]]=event[_$_f464[28]][_$_f464[27]];holder[_$_f464[30]](image,holder[_$_f464[29]]);};reader[_$_f464[31]](file);}else {alert(_$_f464[32])}}function readfiles(files){var formData=tests[_$_f464[9]]? new FormData():null;for(var i=0;i<1;i++){if(tests[_$_f464[9]]){formData[_$_f464[34]](_$_f464[33],files[i])};previewfile(files[i]);};if(tests[_$_f464[9]]){var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();xhr[_$_f464[37]](_$_f464[35],DOMAIN_NAME+_$_f464[36]);xhr[_$_f464[20]]=function(){progress[_$_f464[38]]=progress[_$_f464[39]]=100;progress[_$_f464[38]]=progress[_$_f464[39]]=0;if(xhr[_$_f464[40]]!==_$_f464[41]){console[_$_f464[42]](xhr[_$_f464[40]]);uploaded_image_url=xhr[_$_f464[40]];$(_$_f464[25])[_$_f464[24]](_$_f464[23])[_$_f464[22]](_$_f464[43]);var temp_img= new Image;temp_img[_$_f464[20]]=function(){$(_$_f464[49])[_$_f464[46]](_$_f464[47],_$_f464[48])[_$_f464[46]](_$_f464[44],_$_f464[45]);$(_$_f464[54])[_$_f464[53]]()[_$_f464[51]](_$_f464[52],temp_img[_$_f464[52]])[_$_f464[51]](_$_f464[50],temp_img[_$_f464[50]]);$(_$_f464[54])[_$_f464[46]](_$_f464[57],_$_f464[58])[_$_f464[46]](_$_f464[55],_$_f464[56]);image_context[_$_f464[59]](temp_img,0,0);$(_$_f464[61])[_$_f464[51]](_$_f464[52],temp_img[_$_f464[52]])[_$_f464[51]](_$_f464[50],temp_img[_$_f464[50]])[_$_f464[46]](_$_f464[52],_$_f464[60]);var cv=document[_$_f464[1]](_$_f464[62]),ctx=cv[_$_f464[64]](_$_f464[63]);ctx[_$_f464[59]](temp_img,0,0);image_effect_saturate(ctx);image_effect_saturate(ctx);image_effect_saturate(ctx);$(_$_f464[65])[_$_f464[51]](_$_f464[52],temp_img[_$_f464[52]])[_$_f464[51]](_$_f464[50],temp_img[_$_f464[50]])[_$_f464[46]](_$_f464[52],_$_f464[60]);cv=document[_$_f464[1]](_$_f464[66]);ctx=cv[_$_f464[64]](_$_f464[63]);ctx[_$_f464[59]](temp_img,0,0);image_effect_sepia(ctx);image_effect_sepia(ctx);image_effect_sepia(ctx);$(_$_f464[67])[_$_f464[51]](_$_f464[52],temp_img[_$_f464[52]])[_$_f464[51]](_$_f464[50],temp_img[_$_f464[50]])[_$_f464[46]](_$_f464[52],_$_f464[60]);cv=document[_$_f464[1]](_$_f464[68]);ctx=cv[_$_f464[64]](_$_f464[63]);ctx[_$_f464[59]](temp_img,0,0);image_effect_grayscale(ctx);image_effect_grayscale(ctx);image_effect_grayscale(ctx);$(_$_f464[69])[_$_f464[51]](_$_f464[52],temp_img[_$_f464[52]])[_$_f464[51]](_$_f464[50],temp_img[_$_f464[50]])[_$_f464[46]](_$_f464[52],_$_f464[60]);cv=document[_$_f464[1]](_$_f464[70]);ctx=cv[_$_f464[64]](_$_f464[63]);ctx[_$_f464[59]](temp_img,0,0);image_effect_addnoise(ctx);image_effect_addnoise(ctx);image_effect_addnoise(ctx);$(_$_f464[71])[_$_f464[51]](_$_f464[52],temp_img[_$_f464[52]])[_$_f464[51]](_$_f464[50],temp_img[_$_f464[50]])[_$_f464[46]](_$_f464[52],_$_f464[60]);cv=document[_$_f464[1]](_$_f464[72]);ctx=cv[_$_f464[64]](_$_f464[63]);ctx[_$_f464[59]](temp_img,0,0);image_effect_bc(ctx);image_effect_bc(ctx);image_effect_bc(ctx);$(_$_f464[73])[_$_f464[51]](_$_f464[52],temp_img[_$_f464[52]])[_$_f464[51]](_$_f464[50],temp_img[_$_f464[50]])[_$_f464[46]](_$_f464[52],_$_f464[60]);cv=document[_$_f464[1]](_$_f464[74]);ctx=cv[_$_f464[64]](_$_f464[63]);ctx[_$_f464[59]](temp_img,0,0);image_effect_tint(ctx);image_effect_tint(ctx);image_effect_tint(ctx);$(_$_f464[75])[_$_f464[51]](_$_f464[52],temp_img[_$_f464[52]])[_$_f464[51]](_$_f464[50],temp_img[_$_f464[50]])[_$_f464[46]](_$_f464[52],_$_f464[60]);cv=document[_$_f464[1]](_$_f464[76]);ctx=cv[_$_f464[64]](_$_f464[63]);ctx[_$_f464[59]](temp_img,0,0);image_effect_vignette(ctx);setTimeout(function(){$(_$_f464[77])[_$_f464[53]]();$(_$_f464[79])[_$_f464[78]]();$(_$_f464[49])[_$_f464[50]](dev_height-216)[_$_f464[82]]({"opacity":_$_f464[80],"filter":_$_f464[81]},300);$(_$_f464[49])[_$_f464[84]](_$_f464[83])[_$_f464[50]](dev_height-216);$(_$_f464[54])[_$_f464[85]](300);crop_coordinates={x:0,y:0,width:temp_img[_$_f464[52]],height:temp_img[_$_f464[50]]};crop_coordinates[_$_f464[86]]=$(target)[_$_f464[52]]()/crop_coordinates[_$_f464[52]];console[_$_f464[42]]($(target)[_$_f464[52]]());$(_$_f464[89])[_$_f464[88]](_$_f464[87]);$(_$_f464[91])[_$_f464[90]](_$_f464[87]);$(_$_f464[92])[_$_f464[78]]();original_image=true;},400);};temp_img[_$_f464[26]]=uploaded_image_url;$(_$_f464[92])[_$_f464[78]]();}else {console[_$_f464[42]](_$_f464[32])};};if(tests[_$_f464[10]]){xhr[_$_f464[7]][_$_f464[93]]=function(event){if(event[_$_f464[94]]){var complete=(event[_$_f464[95]]/event[_$_f464[96]]*100|0);progress[_$_f464[38]]=progress[_$_f464[39]]=complete;console[_$_f464[42]](xhr[_$_f464[40]]);}}};xhr[_$_f464[97]](formData);};}if(tests[_$_f464[98]]){holder[_$_f464[99]]=function(){this[_$_f464[12]]=_$_f464[100];return false;};holder[_$_f464[101]]=function(){this[_$_f464[12]]=_$_f464[21];return false;};holder[_$_f464[102]]=function(e){this[_$_f464[12]]=_$_f464[21];e[_$_f464[103]]();var thisfiles=e[_$_f464[105]][_$_f464[104]];console[_$_f464[42]](thisfiles[0]);if(acceptedTypes[thisfiles[0][_$_f464[19]]]){readfiles(thisfiles)}else {alert(_$_f464[32])};};}else {fileupload[_$_f464[12]]=_$_f464[14];fileupload[_$_f464[108]](_$_f464[107])[_$_f464[106]]=function(){var thisfiles=this[_$_f464[104]];if(acceptedTypes[thisfiles[0][_$_f464[19]]]){readfiles(thisfiles)}else {alert(_$_f464[32])};};};$(_$_f464[89])[_$_f464[112]](_$_f464[109],function(){$(_$_f464[111])[_$_f464[110]](_$_f464[109])});$(_$_f464[111])[_$_f464[112]](_$_f464[113],function(){var thisfiles=$(_$_f464[111])[_$_f464[114]](_$_f464[104]);console[_$_f464[42]]($(_$_f464[111])[_$_f464[114]](_$_f464[104]));if(acceptedTypes[thisfiles[0][_$_f464[19]]]){readfiles(thisfiles)}else {alert(_$_f464[32])};});
```

Comment: Please add your code here instead of providing links. It makes it easier for us to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: And those aren't errors, just information. Errors are usually in red. I'd suggest troubleshooting your code, both the javascript and whatever you're using server-side.

Comment: Friend do not give to put the HTML code here is too big

Comment: Alas, no code, no help, because we are not mind readers. And it probably has nothing to do with the HTML and everything to do with the PHP code for uploading the image. If you can't find it or can't figure out how to troubleshoot it, you may want to hire someone to look into it.

Comment: Friend, the file upload_photo.php is already there

Comment: I can't see your images of your errors `:-(` . There are no valid links. Please update you question.

Comment: Updated friend @Martin

Comment: Friend already here the codes of the files thank you @aynber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["name"], $full_path.$destination);
```

to this:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $full_path.$destination);
```

According to [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php).

Comment: Did not work, friend @harisdev PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpBBak07' to '/home/lojavirt/public_html/photos/2018/Jan/5a4d42f6e81ba.' in upload_photo.php on line 26

Comment: That might be permissions issue then. Try to set your folder photos/2018/Jan/5a4d42f6e81ba permissions to 755 and try again.

Comment: Friend showed this error PHP Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/php0q3wEY' to '/home/lojavirt/public_html/photos/2018/Jan/5a4d466f66c12.' in upload_photo.php on line 26 @harisdev

Comment: In Console ta giving this error .canvas_properties_panel .banner_autoplay undefined, .canvas_properties_panel .banner_animate_from_border undefined, .canvas_properties_panel .banner_loop_slides undefined, .canvas_properties_panel .banner_pause_on_mouseover undefined, .canvas_properties_panel .banner_responsive  undefined, .canvas_properties_panel .banner_link_url   off in banner_functions.js @harisdev

Comment: Friends thanks, the directory path missing from the folder, Resolved